# How do I use the output generated from another output with a Shiny app?

Tags: r, input, shiny, output

I want to use a dataframe that is generated based off an input in multiple outputs. Is there a way I can generate this output just once versus doing it for every output?

For example,The user will generate give their input such as a date

```
dateRangeInput("date", label = "Delivered Date Range: ", start = ld, end = hd)
```

I will then use that date range input in multiple outputs. However, two outputs require the same query to get the same dataframe using that input.

```
output$p1 <- renderPlotly({
  q1 <- "
  SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE date > '"
  q2 <- input$date[1]
  q3 < "'"
  p1_df <- sqlQuery(DS, q)
  plot_ly(data = p1_df, x = ~x, y = ~y)
})

output$p2 <- renderPlotly({
  q1 <- "
  SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE date > '"
  q2 <- input$date[1]
  q3 < "'"
  p2_df <- sqlQuery(DS, q)
  plot_ly(data = p2_df, x = ~x, y = ~y)
})
```

Is there a way in Shiny that I only have to run this query once as to make my app more efficient?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the query into reactive function (function inside "server" part of the app):

```
sqlData <- reactive({
  q1 <- "
  SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE date > '"
  q2 <- input$date[1]
  q3 < "'"
  p1_df <- sqlQuery(DS, q)
  return(p1_df)
})
```

and then just call it inside renderPlotly:

```
output$p1 <- renderPlotly({
  p1_df <- sqlData()
  plot_ly(data = p1_df, x = ~x, y = ~y)
})

output$p2 <- renderPlotly({
  p2_df <- sqlData()
  plot_ly(data = p2_df, x = ~x, y = ~y)
})
```

Comment: Late reply but thank you for the answer. I marked it as the answer and implemented it into my app.